# Python: Division by larger numbers slower?

Tags: python, performance

Why does dividing by the larger factor pair result in slower execution?

My solution for https://codility.com/programmers/task/min_perimeter_rectangle/

```py
from math import sqrt, floor

# This fails the performance tests
def solution_slow(n):
    x = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(x, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 2*(i + n / i))

# This passes the performance tests
def solution_fast(n):
    x = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(x, 0, -1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 2*(i + n / i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not division that slows it down; it's the number of iterations required.

Let `L = xrange(0, x)` (order doesn't matter here) and `R = xrange(x, n+1)`. Every factor of `n` in `L` can be paired with exactly one factor of `n` in `R`. In general, `x` is much, much smaller than `n/2`, so `L` is much smaller than `R`. This means that there are far more elements of `R` that don't divide `n` than there are in `L`. In the case of a prime number, there *are* no factors, so the slow solution has to check every value of the much larger than instead of the much smaller set.

Answer (score 1):

That's obvious. The first function loops *many* more times.

Note that `sqrt(n) != n - sqrt(n)`! in general `sqrt(n) << n-sqrt(n)` where `<<` means *much* lesser than.

If `n=1000` the first function is looping `969` times while the second one only `32`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the of iterations is the key which makes perfomance a little bit different between your functions as @Bakuriu already said. Also, xrange could be slightly more expensive than using a simple loop, for instance, take a look f3 will perform a little better than f1 & f2:

```
import timeit
from math import sqrt, floor


def f1(n):
    x = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(x, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 2 * (i + n / i)


def f2(n):
    x = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(x, 0, -1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return 2 * (i + n / i)


def f3(n):
    x = int(sqrt(n))

    while True:
        if n % x == 0:
            return 2 * (x + n / x)

        x -= 1


N = 30
K = 100000

print("Measuring {0} times f1({1})={2}".format(
    K, N, timeit.timeit('f1(N)', setup='from __main__ import f1, N', number=K)))
print("Measuring {0} times f1({1})={2}".format(
    K, N, timeit.timeit('f2(N)', setup='from __main__ import f2, N', number=K)))
print("Measuring {0} times f1({1})={2}".format(
    K, N, timeit.timeit('f3(N)', setup='from __main__ import f3, N', number=K)))

# Measuring 100000 times f1(30)=0.0738177938151
# Measuring 100000 times f1(30)=0.0753000788315
# Measuring 100000 times f1(30)=0.0503645315841
# [Finished in 0.3s]
```

Next time, you got these type of questions, using a profiler is highly recommended :)